# PHP MySQLi to formatted xlsx worksheet as columns

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Looking at programs like PHP Excel and the newer PHPSpreadsheet, I'm hoping to send results from my mysqli query to Excel in a formatted workbook.  However, rather than having the data come into rows, I need each record to display in columns.

STANDARD:

```
           Name      Age       Sex
 Row1      Tom       30        Male
 Row2      Dick      35        Male
 Row3      Harriett  29        Female
```

WHAT I NEED

```
           Row1      Row2      Row3
 Name      Tom       Dick      Harriet
 Age       30        35        29
 Sex       Male      Male      Female
```

Anyone familiar with how I can achieve this either using PHPSpreadsheet of another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPSpreadsheet has a setCellValueByColumnAndRow method that makes this kind of manipulation easy.

```
$column = 2            
foreach($records as $record){
   $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
        ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, 2, $record->name)
        ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, 3, $record->age)
        ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, 4, $record->sex);
 $column++;
   //$row++;  original mistake 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Knowing the name of the method makes it a lot easier to find.

Comment: I had to change `$row++`; to  `$column++;` for it to work